# curl display folders content- Error 401 unauthorized

Tags: authentication, terminal, box-api

[image]

I have attached the screenshot of the error that occurred while trying to list the folder's content in box account using TERMINAL.Followed the link:

"http://developers.box.com/docs/"
Help me to rectify the error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message indicates that your access token is invalid.  Perhaps it expired?

Comment: Ya but every time I refresh the api-key and generate the new access token and assign the value. Still getting the same error, what can be done? Do we need to generate the api-key frequently or one api-key is enough for completing the whole project.

Comment: What method(s) are you calling to get your access token?

Answer (score 0):

`401 Unauthorized`indicates that the `access_token`you have is invalid or expired. Based on the comments, it sounds like you're confusing the API key AKA client_id with the access_token. The API key identifies your app, but the access_token is necessary to actually access a user's account. The process for generating an access_token is outlined here: developers.box.com/oauth